# Was a larger version of Chitin I: The Harvest Wars ever released?

Tags: chitin-1

I owned Metagaming's Chitin I: The Harvest Wars (MicroGame 2) when I was a kid. I have a possibly flawed recollection that a larger bookshelf game using the Hymenoptera universe was released or possibly just planned. Does anyone know anything about it? I may also be confusing this with a similar game 3M or Avalon Hill game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my own research, it appears that a larger game based on the Hymenoptera universe was planned. There were a range of Chitin 25mm miniatures in the prototyping stage when Martian Metals was destroyed in a fire, pushing the release back. As Metagaming itself unfortunately went out of business a few years later, the larger game was never released.

Source: http://theminiaturespage.com/boards/msg.mv?id=99895

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a letter to Metagaming when I was a kid and they wrote back that additional games were planned in the series.

It's a shame that never happened. There's an article out on the web from a magazine that added ranged units.

It's my understanding the rights are for sale, but the asking price is high. Really high. Last I heard about it was late 90s or early 2000s... and it was in the $125K range.

Answer (score 0):

You can get info at [www.strategicwargames.org](https://www.strategicwargames.org).

We have produced the long awaited Chitin Advanced Hymenoptera Game system.